# Variable Calculation Strings with Variable Operators

Tags: variables, reporting-services, evaluation

I am currently working to integrate a third party mapping tool into my current system.

Problem is the tool itself as it replaces an existing system needs certain tweaks, as well as a summarized version of data to make SSRS reporting much faster.

Right now all I would like to do from a dataset perspective is return something similar to Sum(Numerator1) & First(Operator1) & Sum(Numerator2) & First(Operator2) & Sum(Numerator3) & First(Operator3) -- If Needed for another Numerator

The problem I have is my calculation can in theory be anything, so even storing it like this will be a huge pain.

so I'm passing balances into each one of those fields, Numerators being numbers and operators being (+,-,*,/).  The reason I see this being my only option is I need Numerator's to be able to fluctuate between groups so if I'm grouping 5 rows vs 10 rows or a full total together I am still doing the same calculation my balances are just changing.

Problem is how can I make SSRS evaluate whatever I have to pass in here, and is it possible to do this as a string.

Division is the kicker here and the main reason I have to do this in the report as I might have data for 20 units.  I need to provide the initial calculation for each unit as well as provide the calculation with each of the balances summed for all 20 units to figure say a percent of sales or something.

If I do this in the report I would have to have a total for each unit and then for the overall total.  I don't want to do this because the report will have untold amount of additional sub totals and trying to bring it the final balance back in the query just will not work.

I appreciate any help or ideas anyone has for this.

Thank you,
Striker~

Answer (score 0):

You can't evaluate a string as an expression in SSRS.

If you have the time and the know-how, then you could write a function in VB.net that parses the expression and returns the result.

You would then call that function from your report like so:

```
=Code.ParseString(Fields!MyStringExpression.Value)
```

Without telling us ***why*** your calculation could be anything, we can't provide much more information!